# Sending Emails in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am developing an email application. I want to use gmail. How can I apply this? 
 My demo applicating is giving the error:

> Problem while sending email please check gmail server details.

How can I solve this?

Comment: We don't know what code you've written or any details about the error you're seeing.  For example, if you're catching an exception and displaying the text that you're showing us then this text tells us nothing about what caused the exception.  There are *many* examples available online for sending email in C#, specifically using Gmail as the target SMTP service.  What specifically have you tried and how specifically is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
  private static void Send(string toEmailAddress, string subject, string message)
        {
               var mail = new MailMessage
            {
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com"),
                Body = message,
                Subject = subject,
                To = {new MailAddress(toEmailAddress)}
            };


            var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            {
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "Password123"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };


            smtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
```